# Git unable to sign commits

Tags: git, macos, gnupg

I followed the [instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/telling-git-about-your-signing-key#telling-git-about-your-gpg-key) on Github to setup Git signing, but I
get the following error when I try to sign and commit. I searched online but I fail to the reason why `--help` is being included in the command to sign. I am on a Mac (M2) and Git version is 2.40.1

```
╭─rishabh@WKW305277K ~/Development/src  ‹feature/list-by-currency*›
╰─➤  GIT_TRACE=1 git commit -m "Initial commit"

13:02:32.970213 git.c:439               trace: built-in: git commit -m 'Initial commit'
13:02:32.991133 run-command.c:655       trace: run_command: --help --status-fd=2 -bsau 6C3C23C559AA013D352F8790061E0F7BCE5EABB8
error: cannot run --help: No such file or directory
error: gpg failed to sign the data:
(no gpg output)
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

To help debug the issue here are the requested information:

1. Content of `~/.gitconfig`

   ```
   ╭─rishabh@WKW305277K ~
   ╰─➤  cat ~/.gitconfig

   [filter "lfs"]
       required = true
       clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
       smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
       process = git-lfs filter-process
   [user]
       name = Rishabh
       email = rishabh@example.com
       signingkey = 6C3C23C559AA013D352F8790061E0F7BCE5EABB8
   [init]
       defaultBranch = master
   [pull]
       rebase = false
   [commit]
       template = /Users/rishabh/.gitmessage
       gpgsign = true
   [core]
       excludesfile = /Users/rishabh/.gitignore_global
   [difftool "sourcetree"]
       cmd = opendiff \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
       path =
   [mergetool "sourcetree"]
       cmd = /Applications/Sourcetree.app/Contents/Resources/opendiff-w.sh \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" -ancestor \"$BASE\" -merge \"$MERGED\"
       trustExitCode = true
   [gpg]
       program = /opt/homebrew/opt/gnupg@2.2/bin/gpg
   ```
2. Output of `gpg --status-fd=2 -bsau <key>`

   ```
   ╭─rishabh@WKW305277K ~
   ╰─➤  gpg --status-fd=2 -bsau 6C3C23C559AA013D352F8790061E0F7BCE5EABB8

   [GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED 6C3C23C559AA013D352F8790061E0F7BCE5EABB8 2
   [GNUPG:] BEGIN_SIGNING H8
   ^C
   gpg: signal Interrupt caught ... exiting
   ```

Comment: What do you have for `git config --global --get gpg.program`?

Comment: Do you have `gpg` installed?

Comment: Have you looked at your `~/.gitconfig`? If `gpg.program` is set to `--help`, you'll see it in there. Without your active configuration, the question doesn't contain enough information to be solvable.

Comment: @knittl Yes, I have GPG installed.

Comment: @JimRedmond I have updated the question with more information to help debug.

Comment: @charles-duffy I have updated the question with more information to help debug.

Comment: If instead of passing a full path you just have `gpg.program` set to `gpg`, that would be more similar to your use of `gpg` (not `/opt/homebrew/opt/gnupg@2.2/bin/gpg`) when testing at the command line.

Comment: (without investigating any wrapper created by the Homebrew formula, we don't know that the homebrew gpg is _really_ gpg without extra gunk added on).

Comment: Also, is there any chance your _individual project_ could have `git.program` overridden, even though your global `git.program` is fine? (The easy way to test this: Do you have the same problem in a completely new repository?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the `git.program` was overriden for my individual projects! Thank you for the directions! On creating a new repository I did not face that problem. I am guessing, maybe my IDE would have added it (because of a bug).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution required that I check the output of `git config --global gpg.program` and `git config gpg.program` on individual repositories, and then I noticed that on individual repositories I had the following:

```
╭─rishabh@WKW305277K ~/Development/src  ‹feature/list-by-currency*›
╰─➤  git config gpg.program
--help
```

which I corrected by setting the value as below and it corrected my problem.

```
git config gpg.program gpg
```